# How to send IM message like Skype in Android?

Tags: android

I have to build a feature in my application which allows user to send a skype message.
For this I have installed skype lite client for Android (although offically the download has been currently withdrawn from Skype).
Now how to initiate the activity from my application OR simply send the chat message without bringing it front, assuming I have skype installed in Android & also signed in already.
Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: ok got how to launch skype ..
Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
skypeIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.android.lite","com.skype.android.lite.SkypeActivity"));
startActivity(skypeIntent);
      but still not able to send chat message directly without bringing activity in front. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the application, Skype in this case, has some publicly available Intents you can send (like [Twidroid](http://twidroid.com/plugins/) has for tweeting) it is not possible.

Alternatively you could find some kind of a Skype proxy web-service that you could call from within your application to relay the messages.

Comment: Yes it is not easily possible until that application makes the intent available publicly. In this case {com.skype.android.lite/
com.skype.android.lite.ChatScreen} , for chat window , causes Security exception if called from other application.